# React Router is showing only one of the Switch components and does nothing when others are called

Tags: react-router, react-router-dom

My routing component looks like this:

```
import { Link, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav'

import AllWorkouts from './Workout/AllWorkouts/AllWorkouts';
import WorkoutCreate from './Workout/WorkoutCreate/WorkoutCreate';
import WorkoutDetails from './Workout/WorkoutDetails/WorkoutDetails';
import WorkoutEdit from './Workout/WorkoutEdit/WorkoutEdit';    

const Main = () => {
    return (  
            <Switch>    
                <Route path="/workout/:id/edit" componnet={WorkoutEdit} />
                <Route path="/workout/:id/details" componnet={WorkoutDetails} />
                <Route path="/workout/create" componnet={WorkoutCreate} />
                <Route path="/workout/all" component={AllWorkouts} />    
            </Switch>
    );
}

export default Main;
```

I have included **BrowserRouter** in index.js and the only route that is matching is ***path="/workout/all"***. I cannot call any of the other routs with Link or directly in the URL.
When I call **/workout/all** I can see the component with all the other routes nothing happens.
Thank you!

Below is the other component and I do not see any misspelling error:

```
import { Link, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button'

const AllWorkouts = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Link to="/workout/create">
                <Button variant="outline-primary">Create new workout</Button>{' '}
            </Link>
            <h1>Hello from AllWorkouts</h1>            
        </div>
    );
}
export default AllWorkouts;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have misspelled component in the other routes

```
mport { Link, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav'

import AllWorkouts from './Workout/AllWorkouts/AllWorkouts';
import WorkoutCreate from './Workout/WorkoutCreate/WorkoutCreate';
import WorkoutDetails from './Workout/WorkoutDetails/WorkoutDetails';
import WorkoutEdit from './Workout/WorkoutEdit/WorkoutEdit';    

const Main = () => {
    return (  
            <Switch>    
                <Route path="/workout/:id/edit" component={WorkoutEdit} />
                <Route path="/workout/:id/details" component={WorkoutDetails} />
                <Route path="/workout/create" component={WorkoutCreate} />
                <Route path="/workout/all" component={AllWorkouts} />    
            </Switch>
    );
}

export default Main;
```